# AKS linux instance type choice

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-aks, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

While choosing instance type for a general production workload on AKS with 4 vCPUs, could anyone help with below queries –

- Choosing AMD processor based instances (Dav4) vs Intel based instances – Cost for the former is lesser. Given that production load is not very high, is there any other factor besides cost to be considered while choosing either type (AMD vs Intel)?
- Choosing instance type with temp local storage V/s without temp local storage – Cost for latter is lesser. Not sure if AKS would internally need a local temp storage to manage the control plane. Also not sure whether there will be any use cases where application deployed on AKS would make use of the local temp storage - there are report generation use cases which may need temp storage to generate report.

There is not much difference in cost/hour b/w the options but there was a query about the choice from client; hence wanted this information.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the specifics of the request in my view.

Q: Choosing AMD processor based instances (Dav4) vs Intel based instances ?

Ans:
AMD processors, like Intel processors, provide powerful, cost-effective solutions. The "Da-series" types are generally used for development, testing, and enterprise-grade applications. Cost is also similar only.
refer this for more [information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/partners/directory/amd-corporation/#virtual-machines)

Q: Choosing instance type with temp local storage V/s without temp local storage

Ans:
Using Azure Blob storage, we can mount a file system into a container or pod, which enables you to use blob storage. If multiple pods need concurrent access to the same storage volume, this is recommended.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-static?tabs=secret) gives more information on the same.

Comment: Thanks @Swarna. Are there any use cases as such where a node with temporary storage is recommended. One case I came across in documentation is when we choose to host OS on VM temp storage (Ephemeral OS) instead of managed disk. Are there any other use cases?